# how to make a darkmode toggle in form1, reach childform form 2?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I am making an app with a menubar and a panel to display subforms. I made a darkmode feature that works on the menu and the parantform. (self.backcolor = ...) i chances when i hit a button and runs a method that sets everything to the right colors. But how do I send the code from form 1 (parant) to the child forms?

```
//form1 (parent)
   
public bool darkMode = false;
public Form activeForm = null;

private void OpenChildForm(Form childForm, object btnSender)
{
    if (activeForm != null)
    {
        label1.Text = "active form is not nothing";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "active form is nothing";
    }

    activeForm = childForm;
    childForm.TopLevel = false;
    childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.panelDesktopPane.Controls.Add(childForm);
    this.panelDesktopPane.Tag = childForm;
    childForm.BringToFront();
    childForm.Show();
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    darkMode = true;
    updateSystemColor();
    updateMenuColors();
}

public void updateSystemColor()
{
    this.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(returnSystemColor(darkMode, 0));

    panelMenu.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(returnSystemColor(darkMode, 1));

    button3.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(returnSystemColor(darkMode, 5));
    button4.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(returnSystemColor(darkMode, 5));
    button5.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(returnSystemColor(darkMode, 5));
    button6.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(returnSystemColor(darkMode, 5));
}

public string returnSystemColor(bool darkmode, int index)
{
    String[] lightModeColors =
    {
    /*0*/ "#E2E0DF", //lightmode_5 - primary
    /*1*/ "#C4C3C2", //lightmode_4 - secondary
    /*2*/ "#A7A6A5", //lightmode_3
    /*3*/ "#8B8A89", //lightmode_2
    /*4*/ "#706F6E", //lightmode_1

    /*5*/ "#000000", //black

    /*6*/ "#EB4992", //maroon_shades_1 - infoBar
    /*7*/ "#C82175", //maroon_shades_2 - button
    /*8*/ "#A60059", //maroon_shades_3 - logo

    /*9*/ "#D54359", //red_shades_1 - infoBar
    /*10*/ "#B62342", //red_shades_2 - button
    /*11*/ "#97002B", //red_shades_3 - logo

    /*12*/ "#9FE8D8", //green_shades_5 - infoBar
    /*13*/ "#7CC3B4", //green_shades_4 - button
    /*14*/ "#59A092", //green_shades_3 - logo

    /*15*/ "#AED9E6", //blue_shades_5 - infoBar
    /*16*/ "#84AEBA", //blue_shades_4 - button
    /*17*/ "#5B848F", //blue_shades_3 - logo

    /*18*/ "#E8A36A", //yellow_shades_1 - infoBar
    /*19*/ "#BD7D46", //yellow_shades_2 - button
    /*20*/ "#935924", //yellow_shades_3 - logo
    };

    String[] darkModeColors =
    {
    /*0*/ "#231F1B", //darkmode_5 - primary
    /*1*/ "#3D3934", //darkmode_4 - secondary
    /*2*/ "#5A5550", //darkmode_3
    /*3*/ "#78736D", //darkmode_2
    /*4*/ "#97928C", //darkmode_1

    /*5*/ "#FFFFFF", //white

    /*6*/ "#640027", //maroon_shades_5 - infoBar
    /*7*/ "#85003F", //maroon_shades_4 - button
    /*8*/ "#A60059", //maroon_shades_3 - logo

    /*9*/ "#5C0000", //red_shades_5 - infoBar
    /*10*/ "#790017", //red_shades_4 - button
    /*11*/ "#97002B", //red_shades_3 - logo

    /*12*/ "#0C5D51", //green_shades_1 - infoBar
    /*13*/ "#367E71", //green_shades_2 - button
    /*14*/ "#59A092", //green_shades_3 - logo

    /*15*/ "#083842", //blue_shades_1 - infoBar
    /*16*/ "#335D67", //blue_shades_2 - button
    /*17*/ "#5B848F", //blue_shades_3 - logo

     /*18*/ "#461700", //yellow_shades_3 - infoBar
     /*19*/ "#6B3700", //yellow_shades_3 - button
     /*20*/ "#935924", //yellow_shades_3 - logo
    };

    if (darkMode == true)
    {
        return darkModeColors[index];
    }
    else
    {
        return lightModeColors[index];
    }
}
```

Please help, and I am not very experienced, so an explaination would be greatry appreciated.

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check the answer? If you have any others questions, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a public field in childForm, and either set it directly, or add a constructor that does that.

Example:

```
class ChildForm
{
    //...
    public bool IsDark = false;
}

class ParentForm
{
    ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();
    childForm.IsDark = true;
    //...
}
```

Or you can have a method in the child form:

```
class ChildForm
{
    //...
    public void SetMode(bool isDark)
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

And then call it from the parent form:

```
class ParentForm
{
    ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();
    childForm.SetMode(true);
    //...
}
```